# Laravel mongodb is there a way to combine eloquent "raw" method with "wheres" or "withs"?

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I'm trying to get a filtered list of products from db using laravel eloquent and mongodb:

`Product::where('filter', $value)->get()`

Inside Product a have categories tree list:

```
Product[
  'name' => name,
  'brand' => brand,
  'categories' => [
     'tree' => [
         0 => ObjectId('654e75e86938ea3f9a0fbdd2') //Id of category level0
         1 => ObjectId('654e75e86938ea3f9a0fbdd3') //Id of category level1
         2 => ObjectId('654e75e86938ea3f9a0fbdd2') //Id of category level2
     ]
  ],
  ...
]
```

I want to get Products filtered list with categories data instead of their id only.

I've used lookup in raw method:

```
$products = Product::raw(function($collection){
  return $collection->aggregate([
    [
      '$lookup' => [
        'from' => 'categories',
        'localField' => 'categories.tree',
        'foreignField' => '_id',
        'as' => 'categories.tree'
      ]
  ]
});
```

My problem is that I want to apply some filters and results ordering using eloquent methods that like `Product::where('filter', $filter)->raw(...)`. But this does not work. So my question is:

**Is there any way to combine wheres with raw? Some sort of withRaw maybe?**

Comment: You can try using `whereRaw` like this `Product::where('filter', $value)->whereRaw([])->get();` or else if you want to do it your way use `'$match' => ['filter' => $value,],` before the `$lookup`

Comment: How can i cambine products with categories using whereRaw? And I know about '$match' but I want to avoid doing all filtering options these way. Eloquent is more simply and readable

Comment: It would be like `Product::where('filter', $value)->whereRaw(['$lookup' array here...])->get();`

Comment: You're using an aggregation pipeline and not a normal query so it's not clear from the docs if something like `'$lookup' => [...], '$match' =>  Product::where(...)->toMql()` would work. I think it's your best bet to try though (or even without the `toMql` part

Comment: @apokryfos laravel eloquent has mql support? like `toMql()`. I am aware of [package](https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb) though

Comment: @Adi you only get mongodb support in Laravel through that package. The code OP uses does use that package so I am assuming that is a given